# code igniter form validation error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to code Igniter, I am facing with a little problem while validating form. The problem which i am facing is that the view with error is displayed with the original view. I don't know how to fix it. here is my code

```
<?php
class Tender extends CI_Controller {
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->is_logged_in();
}
function add_nit()
{  
    $data['title'] = 'Add NIT';
    $data['main_content'] = 'tendermanager/add_nit'; 
    $this->load->view('includes/main_template',$data);

    if(isset($_POST['name']))
    {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name', 'required');

            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="alert alert-danger">', '</p>');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false)

        {

            $this->load->view('tendermanager/add_nit');

        }   
        else
        {
        //  redirect('tendermanager/tender/add_nit'); 
            }
    }

} }
```

View 1 (dashboard)

```
<?php $this->load->view('includes/main_header');?>
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top:90px;">
<div class="row-fluid">
<? echo $this->load->view('sidebar');?>

</div>

<div class="span9 well" style="background:#fff;">



<div class="page-header">

  <h1>add <small></small></h1>

</div>

 <?php $this->load->view('tendermanager/add_nit');?>

</div>
```

View 2 (add_nit)

```
<?php
echo form_open('tendermanager/tender/add_nit');?>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Office Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>" size="50" />
<?php echo form_error('name'); ?>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name='basicdetails' value="Get NIT Number" class="btn btn-primary"></button>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your validation is not working because you not include form library inside your constructor

Read [Form Validation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/form_validation.html)

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->is_logged_in();
}
```

Comment: Dear validation is working properly. Giving error messages as well. but the issue is that the form with error is displayed with the original form. I mean the original form is not replaced with the form having errors Instead again the same form is displayed having errors on it.

Comment: if validation is incorrect please load it to same view where it comes